# use of delimiter function from scanner for "abc-def"

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, text-formatting

I'm currently trying to filter a text-file which contains words that are separated with a "-". I want to count the words.

```
scanner.useDelimiter(("[.,:;()?!\" \t\n\r]+"));
```

The problem which occurs simply is: words that contain a "-" will get separated and counted for being two words. So just escaping with \- isn't the solution of choice.

How can I change the delimiter-expression, so that words like "foo-bar" will stay, but the "-" alone will be filtered out and ignored?

Thanks ;)

Comment: this is not clear, can you put some samples of what you want and what you don't want, please?

Comment: @chburd: i think he wants "one two-three - four" to be three words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm guessing at your question here:  you mean that you have a text file with some "real" prose, i.e. sentences that actually make sense, are separated by punctuation and the like, etc., right?

Example:

> This situation is ameliorated - as far as we can tell - by the fact that our most trusted allies, the Vorgons, continue to hold their poetry slam contests; the enemy has little incentive to interfere with that, even with their Mute-O-Matic devices.

So, what you need as delimiter is something that is either any amount of whitespace and/or punctuation (which you already have covered with the regex you showed), or a hyphen that is surrounded by at least one whitespace on each side.  The regex character for "or" is "|".  There is a shortcut for the whitespace character class (spaces, tabs, and newlines) in many regex implementations: "\s".

```
"[.,:;()?!\"\s]+|\s+-\s+"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very simple. One thing to try would be {current-delimeter-chars}{zero-or-more-hyphens}{zero-or-more-current-delimeter-chars-or-hyphen}.

It might be easier to just ignore words returned by scanner consisting entirely of hyphens

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to use the pre-defined classes... makes the regex much easier to read. See java.util.regex.Pattern for options.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
string.split("\\s+(\\W*\\s)?"
```

Reads: Match 1 or more whitespace chars optionally followed by zero or more non-word characters and a whitespace character.

Comment: I should also point out that regex patterns need to be double escaped otherwise the compiler will complain that \foo isn't a valid string character.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("one   two2  -   (three) four-five - ,....|");
scanner.useDelimiter("(\\B+-\\B+|[.,:;()?!\" \t|])+");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next("\\w+(-\\w+)*"));
}
```

**NB**

the next(String) method asserts that you get only words since the original useDelimiter() method misses "|"

**NB**

you have used the regular expression "\r\n|\n" as line terminator. The JavaDocs for java.util.regex.Pattern shows other possible line terminators, so a more complete check would use the expression "\r\n|[\r\n\u2028\u2029\u0085]"

Comment: \B is a zero-width assertion; it matches a position that is not a word boundary. It doesn't consumer any characters, so it makes no sense to add a '+' or any other quantifier to it. Java just ignores the quantifier, but some other regex flavors treat it as a syntax error.

Comment: Also, the OP isn't using "\r\n|\n". He isn't interested in line separators at all. He's just matching the most common whitespace characters along with the punctuation characters in the character class (but he should be using "\s", like @Svante did).

Comment: he used \r\n in useDelimiter(), btw thanks for the first clarification! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple enough: `[^\\w-]\\W*|-\\W+`

- But of course if it's prose, and you want to exclude *underscores*: 
  `[^\\p{Alnum}-]\\P{Alnum}*|-\\P{Alnum}+`
- or if you don't expect numerics:
  `[^\\p{Alpha}-]\\P{Alpha}*|-\\P{Alpha}+`

**EDIT:** These are easier forms. Keep in mind the complete solution, that would handle dashes at the beginning and end of lines would follow this pattern. `(?:^|[^\\w-])\\W*|-(?:\\W+|$)`